# How to get bid simulation reports from AdWords My Client Center?

Tags: keywords, google-ads, reporting, bidding

According to [this article](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+GoogleAds/posts/GdrkHZeAB2y) one can download bid simulation reports on the My Client Center (MCC) level. Unfortunately, I don't see how. When I go to my MCC > Client Reporting > Keyword Performance Report there are no such columns to be selected.